# Setting up an Angular project, with Angular Materials

Tags: angular

I surrender...

All I'm trying to do is put together a step-by-step walkthrough for my company, of how to generate a new **Angular 4** project and add **Angular Materials** to it...  and I can't do it.

I've watched PluralSight videos, read the instructions, Googled like hell, but I just get tied up by the dependencies which, eventually, just leave me with a project which won't run.

Here's how far I've got...

I've created a new Angular project based on the example on Angular's website:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart AngularDemo
cd AngularDemo
npm install
```

I modified the **app.module.ts** file, to allow us to use ngModel (Seriously?!  This wasn't included by default ?!)

```
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';   //  We want to use ngModel !

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
```

Okay, all good so far.
The app runs fine.

Now, I want to include Angular Materials.  I use the command as described on their website:

```
npm install @angular/material @angular/animations --save
```

The following screenshot shows the issues from there...

[image]

As you can see, Materials has a dependency on `@angular/core@4.0.3`

I thought I would be able to add this to my project (with the `--save` parameter) but this isn't allowed.

I thought I would be able to add this globally (with the `-g` parameter) but this also isn't allowed.

So, okay, I'll just add it normally:

```
npm install @angular/core@4.0.3
```

Why would I get an error (see number "3" above), complaining that `@angular/core@4.0.3` has an unmet dependency on, errr, `@angular/core@4.0.3` ?!

I also see that `@angular/animations@4.2.3` reports that I must have `@angular/core@4.2.3` installed  (see number 4 in the screenshot above), so, okay, let's do that...

```
npm install @angular/core@4.2.3
```

At which point, things get even messier...

[image]

So, my `@angular/core@4.2.3` is somehow invalid, and `@angular/router@4.0.3` requires `@angular/core@4.0.3`...  But... but... I had installed this...

It's at this point that I start Googling like hell, finding StackOverflow suggestions which, although they're just 5-6 months old, are now out-of-date, and pulling my hair out.

If I try to use `npm start` to see what start the project is now in, I get a load of errors...

[image]

Actually, if I try `npm install @angular/core@4.2.3 --save` this does seem to work and modify my `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.3",
```

Yet I still see errors about unmet dependencies on `@angular/core@4.2.3`.

I should say, I followed tips from StackOverflow, tried updating the typescript, installing Jasmine and Hammer, and including these in my `app.module.ts` file..

```
npm install typescript@2.3.2 --save 
npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
npm install hammerjs 
npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
```

... plus I made sure that my `systemjs.config.js` file contained the paths of the relevant libraries (why isn't this done automatically ?!)..

```
  '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
  '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
  '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
```

... but.... bottom line... I surrender.

For every error I manage to get rid of, another 5 appear in it's place.

What are the steps I need to take to add Angular Materials to the default startup project from the Angular website..?

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart AngularDemo
```

Thanks for reading...

This stuff is absolutely baffling, it doesn't quite "feel ready yet" and I've wasted a huge number of hours getting nowhere.  I miss the simplicity of Angular 1... ;-)

Comment: I may not provide you a solution, but how about you'd try Angular CLI instead of Quickstart? I has much easier setup and it's ready instantly. I implemented my Angular Material with CLI using command `npm install --save @angular/material` then in `.angular-cli.json` file in `styles` array I added following line: `"../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pi‌​nk.css"` after `styles.css`.

Comment: You should use npm cli instead of cloning quickstart, mainly because of webpack that will greatly help you during dev phase. Als, this seems to fail because your project needs angular 4.2.3 and angular material needs 4.0.3. In my opinion, you should start again with angular-cli with this document as guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started angular-cli is really more simple.

Comment: @Supamiu: Actually, this isn't true.  The QuickStart comes with Angular Core 4.0.0 and works fine, but Angular Materials requires "@angular/animations"  and *that* requires Angular Core 4.2.3 (as my 1st screenshot shows).  I'll give Angular CLI a go, but, seriously, it's bizarre to be told *not* to use the QuickStart provided by Angular themselves...  My head hurts !!   Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: @MikeGledhill Are you sure Angular themselves recommend Quickstar? I just checked their website and they use Angular CLI now: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Yup, fair point...  I actually took this advice from a John Papa PluralSight video.  Will follow the *Angular CLI* tutorial, and see how I get on.  Thanks !!
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/play-by-play-angular-2-quick-start-john-papa-ward-bell/table-of-contents

Comment: Btw, I just realised, some of Angular's pages *do* still recommend creating a fresh app using that nasty GitHub project...  The "Hero Editor" example still has a link to it on the "2. The Hero Editor" page of the tutorial, under a "Follow the setup instructions" link...   I'm not going to be the last person hitting these issues...
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm my findings (and save any other Angular victims from the problems I've seen)...

**Do not use the following command**, as a starting point for your Angular applications.

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart AngularDemo
```

Some of Angular's own tutorial pages do still suggest that this is a valid starting point...  it's not !!

[image]

If you use the `npm install` method, then adding Angular Materials is really straightforward.

There is just one problem with the [Angular Materials tutorial](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) though:

In "Step 4: Include a theme", it tells you:

```
To get started with a prebuilt theme, include the following in your app's index.html:

<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This doesn't work.

On my Windows 7 laptop, it just repeatedly told me that it couldn't find this .css file, even if I copied it into the same folder as my **index.html**, and tried to include it from there.

Instead, you must add this line to your `styles.css` file:

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

(Sigh.)

I picked the wrong week to give up beer...

**(A little while later...)**

I just noticed that my dumb tutorial app now works fine with Angular Materials on Chrome, but quietly throws an exception in IE11.

[image]

Thankfully, this one's simple to fix with a little Googling.  You just need to open `polyfills.ts` and uncomment a few lines:

[image]

But once again, this is an issue which will prevent all IE11 users from being able to use Angular Materials... why isn't this mentioned in their Getting Started tutorial ?!

I picked the wrong week to give up glue-sniffing...